# Very slow CSV import in Django

Tags: python, django, csv, import

I have a working function in my views.py to import a uploaded csv-file in my database (sqlite).
The csv-file has a size of about 760kb and about 2.1k lines of data. It takes me about 9 minutes to import that data with the following simplyfied code. **Is there any faster method?**

````
for row in reader: 
    item.objects.update_or_create( 
        sn = row[0], defaults={ 
        "field_a": row[1], 
        "field_b": row[2], 
        "field_c": row[3], 
        "field_d": row[4], 
        } 
    )``` 

Thank you for your help!
````

Comment: It doesn't appear to be csv import issue. Check if there is something else happening on update or create. Maybe you implicitly call another time-consuming method. There are quite many things that may slow down objects creation but this tiny code snippet isn't sufficient to define them.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is running 2,100 times and each one is creating a call to the DB to create or update the object - that is probably causing it to be slow, although it could be something else, it's hard to say without knowing the wider context of your code. Django has bulk update and bulk create functions in the ORM that consolidate creations/updates into a single DB call:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create

You will need to write some code that will handle the creations and the updates separately as Django doesn't have a bulk update_or_create function